# Flask view raises "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute"

Tags: python, flask

`app.py` defines a `sectors` view that use a `Sectors` class defined in `sectors.py`. When I access the view, I get an `AttributeError`:

```
    sector = sectors.Sectors()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Sectors'
```

```
import sectors

@app.route("/sectors")
def sectors():
    sector = sectors.Sectors()
    return render_template('sectors.html', sector=sector)
```

I imported `sectors`, so it should be a module, not a function, and it does have `Sectors` defined. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your view function has the same name as a name you imported earlier. Since the view function is defined after the import in the file, it is what the name points at.

Either alias the import:

```py
import sectors as sectors_mod

@app.route("/sectors")
def sectors():
    sectors_mod.Sectors()
    ...
```

Or change the name of the function. You can still keep the endpoint name as `"sectors"` for use with `url_for`.

```py
import sectors

@app.route("/sectors", endpoint="sectors")
def sectors_view():
    sectors.Sectors()
    ...
```

In either case, the names of the import and function are distinct, and the endpoint name remains `"sectors"` in both cases, so `url_for("sectors")` still works.