# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests, backend

Trying to add pagination in my flask app but while using request.args.get() getting AttributeError.It's showing that function does not have attribute args, I don't know what I've done wrong here. I tried everything but could not solve this.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'test'

db = mysql.connector.connect(user=app.config['MYSQL_USER'], password=app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
                             host=app.config['MYSQL_HOST'], database=app.config['MYSQL_DB'])
cursor = db.cursor()

@app.route('/')
def thumbnails():
    # Retrieve the image URLs from the database
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM sheet1')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    
   
    
    # Paginate the image URLs
    page = int(request.args.get['page']) if 'page' in request.args else 1
    per_page = 12
    offset = (page - 1) * per_page
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, total=len(image_urls), css_framework='bootstrap4')
    image_urls = image_urls[offset:offset+per_page]
    
 
    
    # Pass the image URLs and pagination object to the template
    return render_template('index.html', rows=rows,pagination=pagination)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

This is the error I'm facing.

```
  File "C:\Users\acer\ProjectP\app.py", line 29, in thumbnails
    page = int(request.args.get['page']) if 'page' in request.args else 1
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
```

Comment: `request` is a function. What did you expect it to be instead?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `request.args.get['page']` with `request.args.get('page')`.

`get` is a function, and you're using it as a dictionary. Alternatively, you can do: `request.args['page']`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you and I solved it. Hopefully, we share the same case and you can confirm.

The other people haven't really answered why the 'request' object has no attribute args.

In my case, it was because my app thought that 'request' was a function.
After I saw this error, I tried printing the 'request' to see why it didn't have any 'args'. And I got

```
<function request at 0x0000019ef47391f0>
```

So why does my app think that 'request' is a function? It turns out, I defined 'request' as a function by accident further down in my code:

```
@app.route("/request")
def request():
```

So yeah, after importing request, I defined request. Don't do that.
I'm guessing that you did that somewhere in your code, but didn't show it in this post, so your app thinks request is something else, and not the request from Flask.

This post is similar to yours. [Flask view raises "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160486/flask-view-raises-attributeerror-function-object-has-no-attribute)